# Iterate over children, find last element

Tags: reactjs

I work on breadcrumb component and I iterate over children like:

```
renderChildren = () => {
  const { children, divider } = this.props;
  return (
    React.Children.map(children, child => (
      <>
        {child}
        {divider}
      </>
    ))
  );
}
```

Divider is between elements in breadcrumb and on last element in breadcrumb I do not want to put divider. One picture, I do not want to display last chevron (divider):

[image]

Comment: For TypeScript: {(index < React.Children.count(children) - 1) && divider} Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
renderChildren = () => {
  const { children, divider } = this.props;
  return (
    React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => (
      <>
        {child}
        {(index < children.length - 1) && divider}
      </>
    ))
  );
}
```

Update:

> `const children: React.ReactNode Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2533)`

Is out of scope of this answer, but to handle this scenario

```
renderChildren = () => {
  const { children, divider } = this.props;
  if (children) { // this fixes error above
    return (
      React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => (
        <>
          {child}
          {(index < children.length - 1) && divider}
        </>
      ))
    );
  }
  return null
}
```

That error comes because you defined your prop as `children?: ReactNode`, because it's optional TypeScript secures you from undefined values

Comment: Nitpicky, but would removing the -1 and using < be cleaner?

Comment: < required actually

Comment: Really cool solution, really, but I got error from TypeScript (we code in TS to have types in source code): const children: React.ReactNode
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.ts(2533)

Comment: Now I have: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339) but understand that it is not related the question. Thanks!!

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly nice answer! Upvoted. Kind of a side-question, do you mind giving a brief explanation on why you would using `React.children.map()` over just your standard `this.props.children.map()`

Comment: I personally use `this.props.children.map`

Answer (score 1):

You could use index and check if it equals to the length of the `children` array:

```
renderChildren = () => {
  const { children, divider } = this.props;
  return (
    React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => (
      <>
        {child}
        {index !== children.length-1 && divider}
      </>
    ))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `children.length` is wrong and not typesafe; it simply 'happens to work', and may be broken in future versions of react. `ReactNode` can be null, which will break this even right now.

You should use the react [top level api](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) to process children;

- use `React.Children.toArray` to determine the number of child elements.
- use `React.Children.map` to map the child elements to new elements.

Like this:

```
export const Breadcrumb = (props: { divider: () => ReactNode, children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    const childCount = React.Children.toArray(props.children).length;
    return (<>
        {React.Children.map(props.children, (child, index) => {
            if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                const isLastChild = index === childCount - 1;
                if (isLastChild) {
                    return React.cloneElement(child, {style: {border: "1px solid #ff0000"}})
                }
                return (<>
                    {child}
                    {props.divider()}
                </>);
            }
        })};
    </>);
}
```

eg.

```
<Breadcrumb divider={() => <span> &gt; </span>}>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>C</span>
</Breadcrumb>
```

Answer (score 1):

**THIS WORKS FOR ME BETTER**

```
  return Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
    const isLastChildrenIndex = index === Children.count(children) - 1;
    return (
      <>
        {child}
        {isLastChildrenIndex &&  <Divider />}
      </>
    );
  });
```

Comment: What you mean by "better"?

Comment: because in some cases children.length didint work for me